# How to convert column of text to CSV

Tags: unix, csv

I have the following output from a command in Unix:

```
"10" 
"30"
"u"
"hello"
```

And I want it in the following CSV format without the trailing comma:

> "10","30","u","hello"

I tried `tr '\n' ','` but that leaves a trailing comma.

Being new to Unix, I am not sure how to go about achieving what I'm trying. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply remove the trailing comma with sed.

```
# echo '"10"
"30"
"u"
"hello"' | tr '\n' ',' | sed s/',$'/\\n/g

"10","30","u","hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just to add that its amazing how much you can achieve by using simple Unix commands.